# How can I get a list of all files by exclude a string?

Tags: python, operating-system, glob

I have a folder full of files:

```
aaa.sh
bbb.sh
ccc.sh
aaadomain.sh
hhhdomain.sh
yyyydomain.sh
aaadomainasssa.sh
```

When I do this, I get the list of all files

```
import glob,os
filelist = glob.glob('*.sh')
```

But, how can I exclude all files that have `domain` as a String in the filename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `filter` if you're planning to iterate over `filelist`:

```
for f in filter(lambda x: 'domain' not in x, glob.glob('*.sh')):
    ... # do something with f
```

Alternatively, use a *list comprehension*:

```
filelist = [x for x in glob.glob('*.sh') if 'domain' not in x]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a list comprehension.

```
>>> [i for i in glob.glob('*.sh') if 'domain' not in i]
['aaa.sh', 'ccc.sh', 'bbb.sh']
```